# Meaning of Input Leakage Current vs Shutdown Current and Quiescent Current

Tags: power, low-power, calculation, quiescent

I am looking at an IC [load switch](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AP22913.pdf) that has values for Quiescent Current, Shutdown Current, and Leakage Current.   My understanding is that Quiescent Current is current drawn by the IC in the "on" state and the Shutdown Current is the current drawn when in the "off" state, but I don't know what Leakage Current means and how it affects the total current picture.  In other words, to calculate the total current used in my system.

For example, I figure I need to take the **duration in shutdown state** * **shutdown current** + **duration in ON state** * **quiescent current** but I don't know where Leakage Current fits in this calculation and what it means.  ie, is Leakage Current included already in Shutdown Current or vice versa or somethng else?

Comment: Leakage current means some *unwanted* current from some pin relative to some other pin. They used to show circuits that demonstrated how each of these measurements were performed. But you'd probably have to call Diodes, Inc. to get that information, now. Without a conversation with an FAE from Diodes, you can just take it as given that the package leaks about a microamp or so. From the input to the output pin, from the input to ground, from the ON pin to ground, and I'd expect it from any pin to any other pin given what I see. Just think of the epoxy package as a 5 MOhm resistor with pins.

Comment: So for battery calculations, you're saying I should add leakage as something that's happening all the time?

Comment: Without a conversation with Diodes, that would be the safer assumption from a quick glance over the datasheet. They mention leakage in at least three different circumstances. All three are pretty different and yet about the same magnitude. I'm led to imagine that the part "just leaks" and if you were to bother with good measurement techniques you'd find that it leaks from any given pin to any given other pin. I'd tend to assume it would be proportional to the voltage difference between the pins. But that may be wrong. For now? Yeah. It leaks. For some apps, that would be bad.

Comment: In some applications I have worried about, the ***actual*** leakage between pins via the epoxy packaging was way way too high. (about \$10^{10} \to 10^{11}\:\Omega\$, which is *normal* for pins buried in epoxy.) Even a COTO relay leaked too much. And so I had to request unbonded dice from the manufacturer and then borrow and learn to use a wire-bonder. So yeah. I wouldn't use these in a situation like that one!